# Memory issue when resizing SCNView via UIViewRepresentable?

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, swiftui, scenekit, metal

In my project, I have a `SCNView` encapsulated in `UIViewRepresentable`, that should resize in height according to the `DragGesture` of another view.

The issue is that when dragging, or after drag gesture ended, the memory usage is abnormally high. Checking for memory leaks in Instruments yielded no leaks. It also only occurs in a physical device, not in Simulator.

When using the Simulator,

[image: simulator mem use]
The memory use is stable at around 19MB, regardless of resizing or not.

When using a physical device,

[image: physical memory use]
The memory use spiked badly upon each resize, and doesn't fall after end. (Worst I've seen was around 1.9GB of memory usage, before crash.)
Any experts here know the reason why it happens, and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: I noticed that after DragGesture ended, if I were to move the camera of the SCNView, the memory will drop back to normal values.

Heres the code of the main ContentView.
Basically its a split view layout where if I were to adjust the `RoundedRectangle` (which acts as a handle), the top and bottom views will resize. It is when resizing that will cause the memory spike issue, which, at worst, will cause a crash, and `Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue`.

```
        VStack {
            SceneView()
                .frame(height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2) + self.gestureTranslation.height)
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
            .frame(width: 40, height: 6)
            .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
            .padding(2)
            .gesture(DragGesture(coordinateSpace: .global)
                    .onChanged({ value in
                        self.gestureTranslation = CGSize(width: value.translation.width + self.prevTranslation.width, height: value.translation.height + self.prevTranslation.height)

                    })
                    .onEnded({ value in
                        self.gestureTranslation = CGSize(width: value.translation.width + self.prevTranslation.width, height: value.translation.height + self.prevTranslation.height)

                        self.prevTranslation = self.gestureTranslation
                    })
            )
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.green)
                .frame(height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2) - self.gestureTranslation.height)
        }
    }
```

Heres the code for the UIViewRepresentable wrapper for the SCNView.

```
struct SceneView: UIViewRepresentable {

    typealias UIViewType = SCNView

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SCNView {
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "SceneAssets.scnassets/Cube.scn")
        let view = SCNView()

        view.scene = scene

        view.allowsCameraControl = true
        view.defaultCameraController.interactionMode = .orbitTurntable
        view.defaultCameraController.inertiaEnabled = true

        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: SCNView, context: Context) {

    }

}
```

Here's the full test project that I've made to describe the issue: https://github.com/vincentneo/swiftui-scnview-memory-issue

Comment: Any reason why it got downvoted? I really wanted to understand what went bad....

Comment: Cannot speak for others, but guess 1) it is preferred to keep the essential parts of the code that show the problem in the content of the question (not a link that may go obsolete). 2) The title of the question is misleading: a spike of memory usage that is freed after an event is NOT a memory leak. Otherwise it is an interesting issue. Out of curiosity: does the memory usage create problems as is?

Comment: @JackGoossen Thanks for the comment, will attempt to add some codes in later. As for the title I didn't know how to name it, as I thought it would be a memory leak, as it was only until recently that I noticed the memory can be released if I were to move the SCNView in any way (as in the camera). If left untouched, the memory does not get freed up by its own. And yes, it does cause problems as it will eventually print "Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue" and crash, if I were to continue resizing.

Comment: I compiled and ran the app on the iOS 14 beta and couldn't see any memory issue. Memory does back to its initial state and the app doesn't crash.

Comment: @mnuages I complied using iOS 14 SDK on Xcode 12 to run for in iOS 13, and while it doesn't crash, the issue still exists, just not as bad, maxed at around 1.0GB, dropping to around 600-700MB, without being back to initial state, unless of manual SCNView interaction.

Comment: @mnuages thinking about it, are you the guy I spoke to during the lab? Anyways if you are, forgot to say thank you, and that I have submitted the bug feedback via feedback assistant, and have tried a UIKit version. Both UIKit (via constraints + storyboard) and SwiftUI versions are exhibiting the same issue, narrowing down to SceneKit potentially.

Comment: @vincent I have the same issue too, is this solved now please? any help will be appreciated

Comment: @Hoby hi, I have kind of abandoned this idea, so I don’t really know. I talked to somebody during the WWDC20, but am unsure if fixed in iOS 14. Was your problem on 14, UIKit, SwiftUI or both?

Comment: @vincent thanks a lot for your response :), Yes with iOS 14.1 and tested with both of swiftui and uikit but the memory issue always happen, only managed to reduce it after applying multisampling4X and reducing the contentScaleFactor but this is not an option as this drastically affect the ar objects quality

Comment: @Hoby I did remember that during the lab, the person told me to do something to help with the situation. I remembered it was to set rendersContinuously to true. If I remembered correctly, that will make memory drop to nominal values once user interaction ends, but the few Hundred MB usage can still be expected during user interaction.

Comment: All this is from my memory (as in what I remember), might check that old code tmr to see if my memories are accurate